# Docker use host port without mapping port

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, smtp

I want to send emails from 2 separate docker containers. Both of these containers need port 25 of the host system but I can only map the port to one of those containers. When I try with the second one it throws this error: `Bind for 0.0.0.0:25 failed: port is already allocated`. How do I use the port of the host system without actually mapping it to one of the containers? The containers need to run on a certain network and not on the host network. I'm using Nodemailer in the docker containers btw.

Comment: You should only need to map port 25 if you want to *receive* mails

Comment: When an external application connects to port 25 on your host, what should happen? This also doesn't appear to be a programming question and better asked on one of the other SE sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. As mentioned here: [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach), you need to add the flag `--add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway` to the run command. That way localhost points to the docker host and not the host of the containers own network. No need to change anything in your code.